# How to scrape table data from specific site JSOUP

Tags: java, jsoup, screen-scraping

I'm trying to scrape some data from table on this site:https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/

Here is the source code of scraper I've tried

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String url = "https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/";
    try{
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Element table = doc.getElementById("main_table_countries_today");
        Elements rows = table.getElementsByTag("tr");

        for(Element row : rows){
            Elements tds = row.getElementsByTag("td");

            for(int i = 0;i<tds.size();i++){
                System.out.println(tds.get(i).text());
            }
        }

    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And here is the output 
China
80,928
+34
3,245
+8
70,420
7,263
2,274
56
Italy
35,713 ....

I would like to scrape only data for one specific country,eg. France.
But I don't have any idea how to do it.

Comment: How is the site organized? Can you select a specific country if you visit with your browser? Once you can do it manually it should not be hard to automate. On the other hand, if you just want to scrape a subset of the available data, writing code to ignore the data you don't want should be straightforward, but requires knowledge of how the site's HTML is organized. Show us what you have and how it's wrong.

Comment: @tripleee Yes, I can select some countries like China, and it will open up a page where I can easily scrape data from div using getElementsByClass option.That's only working for China and few other countries.If I want to scrape data for Algeria I would have to do it by scraping tables and that's where I'm stuck.Inside table there is a tr with class "even" or "odd" and it contains few more tds holding the data.

Comment: A proper question on Stack Overflow would show some example data and an overview of what you have already tried. I'm not a Java person but what you describe should be easy and straightforward with any half-decent HTML parser.

Answer (score 0):

You have to ask first every "td" if it's contain "France" then you can print the row.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String url = "https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/";
    try{
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Element table = doc.getElementById("main_table_countries_today");
        Elements rows = table.getElementsByTag("tr");

        for(Element row : rows){

            Elements tds = row.getElementsByTag("td");
            for(int i = 0;i<tds.size();i++){
                if(tds.get(i).text().equals("France")){
                    System.out.println(row.text());
                }

            }
        }

    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Output:

```
France 14,459 562 1,587 12,310 1,525 222
```